# Load external scripts after Angular view loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I load the angular views by ui-router

```
    ...
  .state('app.page.search', {
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'tpl/page_search.html'
  })
```

I ran into `XXX is not a function` randomly,

How could I make sure the external files are loaded after Angular views are ready?

## tpl/root_layout.html

```
    <div data-ng-include="'tpl/header.html'"></div>
    <div class="content-container no-padding">
        <div class="container-full">
            <!-- <div data-ng-include="'tpl/search.html'"></div> -->
            <div class="app-content-body fade-in-up" ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-include="'tpl/footer.html'"></div>
```

## tpl/page_search.html

```
    <DOM>
    ....
    <DOM>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/scriptA.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/scriptB.js'></script>
```

Comment: how about `$timeout(function(){  //call your function here  })`;

Comment: Use ui router's `resolve` property to do async tasks

Comment: @YinGang it didn't work as expectation

Answer (score 0):

as @Daniel Higueras suggested, use the UI Router's resolve to wait for your assets to load in

```
.state('state', {
    url: '/state',
    templateUrl: 'url/state.html',
    resolve: {
        asset1: function($http) {
            return $http.get();
        },
        asset2: function($http) {
            return $http.get();
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to load your assets after everything's done, you can use the ocLazyLoad service: https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/oclazyload-service

Just use it in your controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($ocLazyLoad) {
    $ocLazyLoad.load('asset1.js').then(
        function(res) {
            // asset 1 is available
        }
    );
    $ocLazyLoad.load('asset2.js').then(
        function(res) {
            // asset 2 is available
        }
    );
});
```

this is helpful when you have large a large asset like `D3` where only one page of your app uses it, so you don't want to pull it in every time your app loads.

Comment: But today my problem is the angular partial views are not loaded yet, I don't know how could I wait for them? Wait for those DOM elements

Comment: @newBike can you please provide more details of the error? what function isn't being called? where is the function located? what's making the actual function call?